# How to find the final excutable file path using file command?

Tags: linux, symlink

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I usually need to find the final executable path for a given command. Let's take `awk` as an example:

```bsh
file $(which awk)
# Output: /usr/bin/awk: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/awk

file /etc/alternatives/awk
# Output: /etc/alternatives/awk: symbolic link to /usr/bin/gawk
```

My question is:

Is there a command (or a flag for `file` command) that will return directly the final path of a given command? in the example above I would like it to return the path of `gawk`

Thank you

Comment: Aside: Don't use `which`, use `type`.

Comment: @Barmar: Could you please elaborate on why type is preferable?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `readlink`:

```bsh
$ readlink -f -- "$(which awk)"
/usr/bin/gawk
```

From `man readlink`:

> **-f, --canonicalize**            canonicalize by following every symlink in
> every component of the given name recursively;
> all but the last component must exist

Comment: I think `readlink -e` is better, because using `-f` will return the current path if the given command doesn't exist.

Comment: @OK-Validation I don't think `readlink -e` offers any advantages, since `$(which ...)` shouldn't print nonexistent paths in the first place. Additionally, `readlink -f` is slightly more portable; `readlink -e` is GNU-specific. (I know you specified Ubuntu, but people using e.g. Alpine could stumble across this and be confused when it doesn't work.)

Answer (score 8):

I found another command `realpath`:

```bsh
realpath -- "$(which awk)"
#Output: /usr/bin/gawk
```

Comment: `command -v awk` is a more portable alternative to `which(1)`.

Comment: @iBug: see the comment of Barmar (under the question post).

Answer (score 5):

In `zsh`, if you have a command name in a variable `$cmd`, `$cmd:c` will expand to the path of the command¹ (via a look-up of `$PATH` / `$path`), and the `:P` qualifier can be used to get the corresponding *realpath* (a symlink-free canonical absolute path to the file as when using the `realpath()` standard C function):

```
$ cmd=awk
$ print -r -- $cmd:c
/usr/bin/awk
$ print -r -- $cmd:c:P
/usr/bin/gawk
$ file -- $cmd:c:P
/usr/bin/gawk: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b863ebf57d3cc33d8e7fed3be0e0b5d235489b46, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
$ namei -l -- $cmd:c
f: /usr/bin/awk
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root bin
lrwxrwxrwx root root awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
drwxr-xr-x root root   /
drwxr-xr-x root root   etc
drwxr-xr-x root root   alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx root root   awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
drwxr-xr-x root root     /
drwxr-xr-x root root     usr
drwxr-xr-x root root     bin
-rwxr-xr-x root root     gawk
```

To avoid the intermediary variable, you can use an anonymous function:

```
$ (){print -r -- $1:c:P} awk
/usr/bin/gawk
```

Or a normal function:

```
$ canonical-path-of() print -rC1 -- $@:c:P
$ canonical-path-of awk ls
/usr/bin/gawk
/usr/bin/ls
```

---

You can also use the `=cmd` operator which is a form of *filename expansion* like *tilde expansion* but that expands to the path of the corresponding command, and still apply the `:P` modifier by this time as a *glob qualifier*²:

```
$ print -r -- =awk
/usr/bin/awk
$ print -r -- =awk(:P)
/usr/bin/gawk
$ print -r -- =blah
zsh: blah not found
```

---

<sup>¹ beware however that if the command in not found in `$PATH`, `$cmd:c` will expand to the same thing as `$cmd`, and `$cmd:c:P` would expand to the path of `$cmd` relative to the current working directory.</sup>

<sup>² this time when the command can't be found, it triggers a fatal error. That `=cmd` expansion can be disabled with `set +o equals`</sup>

Answer (score 5):

If you want to tell the `file` command on Linux to return information about the `awk` command, and to resolve all symbolic links while doing so, then use `file` with its `-L` option:

```bsh
$ file -L -- "$(command -v awk)"
/bin/awk: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b863ebf57d3cc33d8e7fed3be0e0b5d235489b46, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

To resolve all links to get the final absolute path of a command, use `readlink -e`:

```bsh
$ readlink -e -- "$(command -v awk)"
/usr/bin/gawk
```